# Auto email after submitting form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

For school we are having a wine sale. I created a form so people can order the wine they want.
 I searched the web for more than 2 weeks to get a working autoconfirmation mail to the person which filled in the form.
In this mail the total ordered amount gets filled in immediately. This is the reason I can't use the autoconfirmation mail in the Google form. I tried several solutions provided by others but none of them worked.
So far I got it working with a script which runs after pressing a button in the Google sheet but not automatically... Trigger is set on form submission
How should I adjust the code?

```
  function sendEmails() {


  var sheetname = "Bestellingen";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 150;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)

  Logger.log("Data Range: " + dataRange.getA1Notation());

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1];  // First column = email
    var name = row[2];          // Second column = name
    var emailSent = row[3];     // Third column
    var totals = row[4];        //Fourth column = totals count in excel
    var sendername;
    var message;

//this is your message

 message = "Beste " + name + ",\n\nWij hebben uw bestelling goed ontvangen! \nGelieve het bedrag van: " + totals + " over te schrijven op het rekeningnummer van de ouderraad KBC BEXX XXXXX XXXX \nMocht u nog iets willen veranderen aan uw bestelling of een opmerkingen  hebben kunt u altijd een reply sturen op deze bevestigingsmail \nWij hopen dat u van uw wijn(en) zal genieten, \nSanté \n\nHet feestcomitée \n\n"

        // This will show up as the sender's name
        sendername = "Wijnverkoop Freinetschool De boomgaard";

    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Wijnbestelling de Boomgaard";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);

// Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

I will post the author of this work as soon as I find it back..

link to google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13e10IgUC8Toexy1ia8plWOWPrq62dxTAMZfSy0PwDDM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So you have the function set as a Form Submit trigger.  I would change the `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` line to `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");` from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid): A spreadsheet ID can be extracted from its URL. For example, the spreadsheet ID in the URL https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit#gid=0 is "abc1234567".

Comment: See this [Simple Mail Merge tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) and modify it to suit your needs.  I used this for something very similar.  It appears you are calculating total costs, etc.  So you could send all this data in the confirmation email using the information in that tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Google Forms? I think it will make your life much easier.